# How to load different assets based on data pulled from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, multi-tenant, paas

I'm providing a multi-tenant service for customers with the potential of uploading their own design(images/CSS/JavaScript), which made me wonder, what is a suitable way for including different assets for different customers? How is it possible to implement such a feature on RoR? I've already made it possible to distinguish between every customer's theme by using unique login credentials.

I have crammed over Rails' documentations without any relevant data about loading different sets of assets. Also, I've searched SO/Google but I couldn't find anything useful.

**How can I load different assets dynamically based on a changing variable(most likely results pulled from database)**. I'm searching for something like:

```
use_assets(current_tenant.theme_name) #current tenant's theme is loaded(CSS/JS/Images)
```

Comment: How about directing all assets to a specific sub-directory based on the user? Just add that directory to all paths.

Comment: How are the customers uploading their design?  Are they uploading them with something like paperclip or carrierwave?  Editing a TEXT column in the dB?

Comment: @AndyV They idea is that we - the providers - create the design specifically for the customer and set it up aswell. The only thing they does is naming the theme.

Comment: @screenmutt How exactly do you purpose we do it? You mean like modifying `config.assets.paths` by replacing `assets` with `assets/{THEME_NAME}`, and would that work on runtime(i.e., with every request, instead of upon server initialization)?

Comment: In every link to a CSS, JavaScript, or Image, include the extra directory.  In other words, link to `"/stylesheets/user/style.css"` instead of `"/stylesheets/style.css"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tackled a similar scenario by rendering the default layout using the asset pipeline and then rendering any customer-specific assets using javascript_include_tag, etc.  I also wrapped up the details of rendering the assets into a helper so that the top of my layout looked something like this

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Tenantly
    = stylesheet_link_tag :application
    = javascript_include_tag :application

    - if current_tenant && !current_tenant.theme_name.blank?
      = custom_theme current_tenant.theme_name
    ...
```

Here the customer's css can override the base css and the customer's js can replace the standard js where appropriate.  That should allow you to slim down the themes to only those pieces that have to be replaced.

Comment: I've used your method but instead of hard coding the directory path every time, I used helper methods which made my views much more cleaner.

Answer (score -2):

Just [set the asset path](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#changing-the-assets-path) based on the user

```
config.assets.prefix = "/path_of_user_12345678"
```

You said you poured over the docs.  You didn't see this?  Or it doesn't work for some reason?

Comment: config.assets.prefix is an _application level_ configuration.  It will be executed once when the application starts, not each time a request is received.